# Google Cloud Functions and CI/CD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We are considering using GCF for one of our upcoming projects, however there is 1 last thing which there does not seem to be any literature on yet.

All the examples and tutorials focusses quite heavily on deploying your functions manually (using the `gcloud` command).  However, we would like to integrate our functions into our CI/CD workflow.

The CI part is trivial, so our question is around how to structure the project from a CD point of view.  Ideally, you would want your function deployed on push (e.g. master branch to production, development branch to development environment etc).

This should also be quite easy to do if you use 1 repo per function.  However, in any non-trivial application we can expect to have hundreds of functions, which would make the repo per function approach very tedious.

The other problem with repo per function approach is that it is impossible to use any shared logic (e.g. think JWT or CORS).

Another option would be to use 1 repo, with all your functions, and then using the `--source-path` option to specify the function to deploy, however this also makes it impossible to used shared code, since GCF checks out that path as the root and cannot import code higher up the hierarchy.  Also, the 1 repo for all approach will make it incredibly difficult to do push-to-deploy.

How would one go about setting up a GCF project like this?

Comment: isn't it opinion based?

Comment: @SagarV care to elaborate?

Comment: How did you plan to solve code sharing issue in case of repo per function case?

Comment: AFAIK the only way you would be able to do that is create npm modules and import them :(

Answer (score 3):

The Serverless framework has some nice utilities around deploying all, or some, of your functions.

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/

I haven't played with the Google Cloud Functions plugin, but it seems decent.

https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions

When it comes to deploying individual functions in subdirectories - only if they have changed... you'll have to use a little bash foo.

You could set the gcloud project based on the git branch, then loop through each directory that has been changed since a certain tag etc.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD 878850 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/' | uniq | while read line ; do cd $line && gcloud beta functions deploy ; done
```

Hopefully this helps a bit, it's definitely early days for these kind of workflows.